# Interesting things you learned while grading/marking?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, teaching

What are some interesting mathematical things you have learned while grading (or marking, if you prefer) student work? For example, clever proofs that students came up with; nice counterexamples or insights; interesting new questions inspired while grading; even just something you looked up to find out if a student's work was valid. Answers can be things that students wrote, or inspired by something a student wrote, or just something we learned during the grading process in some way.

It is final exams time here, so if anyone can help cast a more positive light on the grading experience, it would be most welcome.

Please refrain from snarky answers about things we learned about our students and their state of knowledge. Please stick to mathematical things. On the other hand, puns about graded rings, marked points, etc., are allowed.

Comment: Ah, I just thought it would be a fun chance to make grading just a little more pleasant. Oh well. I guess I should have posted it in matheducators.SE instead.

Comment: Either that or just Math.SE I would say.

Comment: I learned to be less clever.  I was a linear algebra TA for a professor who found one of my questions "beautiful! The students won't understand it!", and put it as question 1 with my name for attribution on the final. Then he assigned me the task of grading that problem.  Gerhard "Of Course He Was Right" Paseman, 2020.05.07.

Comment: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18297/12530